# Data on historical, cross-country nominal and real yield curves

Tags: inflation, interest-rate, data-request, bonds, yield-curve

1. Various central banks publish their fitted ***nominal*** yield curve estimates: [the Fed](http://www.federalreserve.gov/econresdata/researchdata/feds200628_1.html), [BOE](https://www.bankofengland.co.uk/statistics/yield-curves), [SNB](https://data.snb.ch/en/topics/ziredev#!/cube/rendoblid), [BOC](https://www.bankofcanada.ca/rates/interest-rates/bond-yield-curves/), [ECB](https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/financial_markets_and_interest_rates/euro_area_yield_curves/html/index.en.html) (cf: [Bundesbank](https://www.bundesbank.de/dynamic/action/en/statistics/time-series-databases/time-series-databases/743796/743796?treeAnchor=GELD&statisticType=BBK_ITS&openNodeId=GELDZINS)), [RBA](https://www.rba.gov.au/statistics/tables/#interest-rates), [Russia](https://www.cbr.ru/eng/hd_base/zcyc_params/), [RBI](https://www.rbi.org.in/Scripts/BS_NSDPDisplay.aspx?param=4#).

- (I couldn't find for BOJ; Brazil; BOK; or PBOC. Links for these would be extremely welcome!)

2. Bloomberg has its own estimates of these zero-coupon nominal curves (e.g. USGG10YR for the US ten-year).

These estimates are not the same (at least not always), and in particular they differ in their historical availability: Bloomberg has less data. Just to pick one example, the Russian 10y on Bloomberg (GTRUB10Y Govt) has data since 2010; the central bank's website estimates back to 2003.

**Does any data source have better (i.e. longer) cross-country coverage for nominal yield curves?**

---

Most central banks do not have estimates for historical ***real*** yield curves, i.e. the yields on inflation-indexed bonds. The US and UK do (at the same links); I have not found any other country that does so. Partially this is because not all countries issue inflation-linked bonds; and among those that do, many do not (or have not historically) issued at enough different maturities to fit a yield curve.

Bloomberg again has its own estimates for many countries (e.g. GTGBPII10Y Govt, for UK 10y). But, as with nominal bonds, these do not span the full history (e.g. UK 10y only goes back to 2007 on BBG; but on the BOE's website, it goes back to 1985.

**Does any data source have better (i.e. longer) cross-country coverage for *REAL* yield curves?**

---

Thank you!